# OpenGL does not draw as expected

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I am currently working my way through the current OpenGL Programming Guide, Version 4.3. I implemented the code of the first example, that should display two triangles. Basically pretty simple.

But nothing is displayed when I run that code (just the black window).

This is the init function where the triangles are created:

```
GLuint vertexArrayObjects[1];
GLuint buffers[1];
const GLuint vertexCount = 6;

void init() {
//  glClearColor(0,0,0,0);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, vertexArrayObjects);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObjects[0]);

    GLfloat vertices[vertexCount][1] {
        {-90.0, -90.0},
        { 85.0, -90.0},
        {-90.0,  85.0},
        { 90.0, -85.0},
        { 90.0,  90.0},
        {-85.0,  90.0}
    };

    glGenBuffers(1, buffers);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    ShaderInfo shaders[] {
        {GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "one.vsh"},
        {GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "one.fsh"},
        {GL_NONE, nullptr}
    };

    GLuint program = LoadShaders(shaders);
    glUseProgram(program);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ((char *)NULL + (0)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

And the very simple draw:

```
void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObjects[0]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

    glFlush();
}
```

But as said, nothing is drawn. Is there an error in my implementation?

*The full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/4XpC2xZQ) and LoadShaders (straight from the books website, so this should be out of interest) is [here](http://pastebin.com/ZQHdRhG4).
The shaders are [here](http://pastebin.com/Ydf4PMSA).*

Comment: It's a long shot, but I don't see any `glViewport`. Maybe also turn off face culling (I never remember what the default is)

Comment: @Grimmy culling seems to be off by default. The example in the book should work without a viewport, it's nowhere in their code and I'm not yet as far to look at more difficult examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i figured out the problem. The application, when built, is run in a entirely different location than the source, and the shader files are not copied in the target directory. Therefore, the program obviously can't read them and nothing is displayed. Replacing the relative shader paths `one.vsh` and `one.fsh` with absolute paths solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the first example in the book, there are no transformations applied (i.e., in the vertex shader, the vertex's position `vPosition` is directly mapped to the output position `gl_Position`).  As such, the coordinate system of the window is *normalized device coordinates*.  Only objects with coordinates between [-1,1] in *x* and *y* will be passed to the rasterizer (and not clipped).  Given the geometry you've specified in the program, the triangles you render completely cover the viewport, so you should see the color you specify in the fragment shader (blue).

Otherwise, your code looks correct.  (Although you don't need to pass `nullptr` into the list of shader for `LoadShaders`.  In only looks for the `GL_NONE`).

Comment: You are right, the coordinates should have been `0.xx` instead of `xx.0`. Still, the window remains black though...